# Make one GameObject be a Squad Member

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to have a GameObject, that follows my Player and always stays to his left.
I dont want to make it a child, because i doesnt look natural and I also played around with the NavmeshAgent, but the second object is too slow/it moves too much.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `NavmeshAgent` is a good solution in general. You tried tweaking `speed`, `angularSpeed`, `acceleration`?

Comment: Yes, I played with it and It usually was too slow or the object accelerated so quick, that it did break out and behave like a pendulum. Maybe I dont get how those 3 values behave together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is this:

1. add an empty GameObject (I call it `SquadPoint`) as a child of that main player object and place it in the desired position (to his left).
2. place your actual squad member directly in the scene (I assume squad member has a controller script attached to it I call it `SquadMemberController`)
3. add the following code to the SquadMemberController script

this should make the squad member follow the SquadPoint and since SquadPoint is a child of main player it moves and rotates with main player.

```
const float threshold = 1f;

public float speed;          //set in inspector
public Transform SquadPoint; //set in inspector

void FixedUpdate(){

   //move towards SquadPoint with given speed
   var distance = SquadPoint.position - transform.position;
   if(distance.magnitude > threshold)
   {
      var direction = distance.normalized;
      transform.position += direction * speed * time.fixedDeltaTime;

      //rotate immediately
      transform.LookAt(SquadPoint.position);
   }
   else
   {
      //... very close to main player
   }
}
```

Comment: I tweaked the rotation a bit to make it fit mine, but its a good olution. Thank you very much!